# Maven Copy in build phase

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My situation is:

- I have a project that scan a directory of libs.
- This project dosen't has dependence with other projects (jars), but this dynamically load them from the directory to his classloader (is a kind of plugin architecture).
- Both projects are under a pom project

Examples of poms:

*Parent*:

```
<groupId>mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
...
```

*"Plugin"*:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
...
```

*"Loader"*:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myloader</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
...
```

Now, I need to generate the jar *"plugin"* and copy it to a defined directory in the project *"loader"* when I build it.

This have to work locally in eclipse and in jenkins automatically builds.

Someone has any idea how I can do this?

Comment: You could configure the jar plugin in your `myplugin` module to put the jar file into the necessary folder. See [outputDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) option.

Comment: I need it in build time, this plugin can do that?

Comment: Can you specify the build order?

Comment: I guess so. How I can set this order manually?

Comment: If both plugin and loader are in `modules` section of parent, you can simply place plugin before loader and this order will be preserved. Otherwise (if they are 2 separate projects), build first and then build second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it solved in four steps:

1. I configure the plugin "maven-assembly-plugin", in my "plugin" project, to copy the jar in a relative path within the project "loader".
2. In this configuration I specify the property "descriptorRef" in *jar-with-dependencies*, this helps me to pack the necessary libraries into the jar
3. I configure the plugin "maven-copy-plugin", in my "plugin" project, to copy the properties in the same relative  path within the project "loader"

The pom.xml from my "plugin" project stay like this:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${my.output.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>     
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.goldin.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-copy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-archive</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <!-- Copy config properties -->
                            <resource>
                                <targetPath>${my.output.directory}</targetPath>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/conf</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.properties</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

On the other hand, I set the project to consume the plugins from the directory *${my.output.directory}*

4. To automate the build in eclipse I create a new type of program builder for the project. This builder run the command "mvn assembly:assembly".

**Step 1**:

[image]

**Step 2**:

[image]

Step 3: In the tab "Build Options" you can configure details of this execution.

For jenkins, I create a dummy plugin which is used only from the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Run maven install for plugin, which puts the resulting jar in your local maven repo.  Then specify plugin in your dependencies section as a dependency.  In this case, even though these projects are siblings, they are only siblings in the sense that the parent is specify the build order when mvn goals are run in parent.  Their actual build artifacts must be included by the sibling if you intend to use it there.